# Java, Андроид, setter/getter

Tags: java, android, setter, getter

Добрый день, понемногу начинаю изучать Java (с андроидом), естественно нужен практикум, так вот, решил написать простенькую программу, в которой есть две кнопки и целочисленная переменная.

Две кнопки  "bHP" и "bDHP" повышают и понижают нашу переменную, для этого я реализовал два класса:
 один, "Main Activity", отображает Текст (в моем случае переменную), и содержит в себе методы кнопок, второй же хранит  в себе ту самую переменную.

В нем я реализовал методы "сеттер" и "геттер". Проблема в том, что все работает, за малым исключением - при нажатии кнопки, насколько я понял, происходит задержка ввиду того, что сначала происходит передача данных переменной; в общем, насколько я понял, "Геттер" я неправильно сделал, на большее не хватает мозгов (из литературы Читаю Сиерра,и Шилда).

Стыдно писать такое, но еще постыднее не знать, простите за неудобство.

Вот код:

```
private int money;
Health heal =  new Health();
int j = heal.getHP();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        money = savedInstanceState.getInt("money", money);

    }
    money();
    healView();
      }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("money", money);

}

public void onMon(View v) {
    int min = 100;
    int max = 150;
    Random r = new Random();
    int money1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    money = money + money1;
    TextView moneyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money_view);
    moneyView.setText(String.format("%08d%n", money));
}

public void money() {
    TextView moneyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money_view);
    moneyView.setText(String.format("%08d%n", money));
}
public void healView (){
    int j = heal.getHP();
    TextView HealthView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Health_view);
    HealthView.setText(String.valueOf(j));}

public void bHP (View view) {
    int j = heal.getHP();
    heal.setHP(10);
    TextView HealthView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Health_view);
    HealthView.setText(String.valueOf(j));}

public void bDHP (View view) {
    int j = heal.getHP();
    heal.setHP(-10);
    TextView HealthView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Health_view);
    HealthView.setText(String.valueOf(j));}
}
```

Класс **Health**

```
public class Health {
    private int HP;

    public int setHP (int newHP) {
        HP=HP+newHP;
        return newHP;
    }
    public int getHP() {
        return this.HP;
    }
}
```

Если можно ,важно не то что сделать.а лучше объяснить или жать ссылку на годную книгу ресурс,но от примера не откажусь тоже,благодарен заранее.

Comment: Прочитал дважды но так и не понял в чём у вас проблема

Comment: @ЮрийСПб при нажатии кнопки  происходит следующие  hHP    первое Нажатие (ничего не просиходит) второе нажатие (+10) третье (+10) ,нажимаем на вторую кнопку hDHP (+10) второй раз (-10) третий раз (-10) нажимем опять на hDP (-10) второй раз (+10)

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно оно работает не так как вы хотите потому что вы сначала берете значение переменной(`int j = heal.getHP();`), затем изменяете ее значение, а затем выводите значение j(то, что взяли до изменения).
Переместите строку `int j = heal.getHP();` ниже в обоих методах(`bHP` и `bDHP`(ужасные, кстати, названия)) и скорее всего все будет нормально

Comment: Извините,но тогда  у меня такой вопрос ,откуда тогда "ТекстВью" будет брать значение переменной ? Насколько я понимаю,мне нужно выводить значение которое я изменяю,а не то которое было до изменение,Спасибо вам большое сейчас буду думать.первые шаги самые трудные

Comment: @Криакл поэтому и надо переместить строку с получением значения ниже, не надо ее убирать. и сеттеры ничего не возвращают и не должны прибавлять передаваемое в них значение к переменной - для этого можно назвать метод add(...) (математическая операция прибавления зовется так же как добавление элемента). в общем - поменяйте пока первые 2 строки местами в методах `bHP` и `bDHP`

Comment: Никита Гордеев Псец,я протупил)Больше чем в момент,когда у меня брали интервью,я как "примат" тыкаю его в низ  в самы,хех,спасибо ва мбольшое Никита,теперья все понял.про АДД сейчас почитаю и реализую,такой вопрос,а что посоветуете почитать ?

Comment: @ Никита Гордеев Теперь я понимаю,зачем в книжках пишут "представьте себя в роли компилятора"

Comment: @Криакл про add - что-то вроде "чистый код", автора не помню, да и книжек подобных много и для разных языков отличаются не сильно. в основном говорится о общепринятых правилах оформления кода: именовать методы так, чтобы не требовались комментарии; один метод - одна ответственность и т.д. от языка к языку меняются, как правило, только "стили" именования - camelCase, snake_case, с какой буквы (большой или маленькой) начинать название переменной/метода/класса

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в классах, типа entity сеттеры и геттеры реализуют просто как

```
public class Health {
  private int HP;

  public int getHP() {
      return HP;
  }

  public void setHP(int HP) {
     this.HP = HP;
  }
}
```

А уже где-то в логике делают с ними что хотят